# Estou tentando fazer um dropdown no html

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando implementar um `DropDownList` em uma `View` minha que serve para formulário, mas preciso que o valor selecionado vá para uma `ViewBag`. Essa é minha `View` ali onde está "**Carro Selecionado**", precisaria transforma minha de `Textbox` em uma `DropDownList`:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o código da minha view:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="carro" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Carro selecionado</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input type="number" class="form-control" id="carro" name="carro" required>
         </div>
</div>
```

Esse é minha `Controller`:

```
public ActionResult FormData()
{
    ViewBag.Veiculo = veiculoDAO.Lista();
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mude suas estruturas para essas:

***Html***

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="carro" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Carro selecionado</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Veiculo")
    </div>
</div>
```

---

***Code***

```
public ActionResult FormData()
{
    var campoId = "nome do campo";
    var campoDescricao = "nome do campo Descricao"  
    ViewBag.Veiculo = new SelectList(veiculoDAO.Lista(), campoId , campoDescricao);
    return View();
}
```

***Referencias:***

- [SelectList Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [DropDownListFor with Dictionaries in ASP.NET MVC and why SelectList wants to kill you](https://nimblegecko.com/dropdownlistfor-with-dictionaries-in-ASP-NET-MVC-and-why-SelectList-wants-to-kill-you/)
- [Create DropDownList using HtmlHelper:](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-dropdownlist-dropdownlistfor)
- [DropDownList and SelectListItem Array Item Updates in MVC](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/May/16/DropDownList-and-SelectListItem-Array-Item-Updates-in-MVC)

Comment: O campoId, é para coloca o Id do banco e a descrição a coluna que eu quero que me traga?

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam isso são o nome dos dois campos da sua tabela !!! campoId seria o nome da chave, e campoDescricao o nome da descrição que vai aparecer na caixa! Ou seja, a sua Lista retorna quais campos para ser colocados como chave e descrição!